# My php script is taking much time to restore small zip file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to Restore the zip file .But the script is taking much time to restore the small size File.On my side my script is taking 7 minutes to restore the 29 MB zip file.  And when i try to Restore that file using Ajax then my script goes struck and i receive this error **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**.This is my php code to restore

```
$filepath='../wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/lib/www.extremenox.co_16_10_2015_06_%i_1445006234.zip';
$backupType="Restore";
RestoreBackup($filepath,$backupType,'Dropbox');
function RestoreBackup($filepath,$backupType,$Storage)
{
 $newpath=$filepath;
 $zip2 = new ZipArchive;
 mkdir(ABSPATH."Restore", 0777);
 if ($zip2->open($newpath) === TRUE) {  
 $zip2->extractTo(ABSPATH."Restore/");
 $zip2->close();
 $directory_path = ABSPATH."Restore/";
 $rootPath = realpath($directory_path); 
 $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
  );
  foreach ($files as $name => $file)
  {
      if(!is_dir($name))
       {
          // echo "in direct";
          if($backupType=='incremental')
          {
            // echo "in incri";

          $source =$name;

          $path2=explode('incremental',$name);

          $destination =$path2[1];

          copy($source,$destination);

          }

           else

           {

        //echo "in restore";    



           $source =$name;

           $path2=explode('Restore',$name);

           $destination =$path2[1];

          copy($source,$destination);



           }



 // exit;

       }

  }

update_option('check_activity_status','clear');

echo "Backup Restored Sucessfully from  ".$Storage."!!";

unlink($filepath);

$path=realpath(ABSPATH."Restore/");

Delete($path);
  }
     }
```

If i try this code using Ajax then this is my javascript code to send request to PHP page

```
  var backupID="3";
  var storageName="dropbox";
  jQuery.ajax({

  type: "POST",

  data: {backupID:backupID,storageName:storageName},

  url:'../wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/lib/wpSafeCloud_RestoreBackups.php',

  dataType: "html",

  success: function(html)
  {}

     });
```

Can any body tell what will be the problem?Why the script is working well without Ajax request.

Comment: what is the value of max_execution_time in your server? `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: I check it.It gives me [see link](http://prntscr.com/8rwoj6)

Comment: from php manual: "This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. ..." also... "Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details." http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Now i have set the time limit to 3600.Like this `set_time_limit(3600)`.But it again taking 7 minutes to restore 29 MB zip file.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not understand your question/problem. What do you meand by "On my side" in the sentence "On my side my script is taking 7 minutes to restore the 29 MB zip file." and then "my script goes struck and i receive this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" ?

Comment: On my side means on my site or on that server where i am executing this code.When i copy that restore process (upgiven) code and paste in some file and then run that file in the browser.Then page starts process and after 7 minutes  page stops and return me the success message..

Comment: And ("my script goes struck and i receive this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" ) means i don't run that file directly in the browser and instead of this i send an ajax request to that page.Here after 1 minute i recieve this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".